# FatFreeFramework copyfrom and update

Tags: php, datamapper, fat-free-framework

I am using FatFreeFramework 3.4.0

I am using Mapper class (SQL)
I am trying to update a row directly from POST but using copyfrom() and than update does not work as expected And save() will try to insert new row.

Here is an example of updating a book price (the use changed the value of the price from 20 to 43):

```
Books Table
id (PK)|price
-------------
2      |20



<from>
    book id: <input  type="text" id="id" name="id" value="2" />
    price: <input  type="text" id="price" name="price" value="43" />
</from>


<?php
function update_book_price(){
    $mapper->copyfrom('POST');
    $mapper->update();
}
```

This is the query the mapper produce:

UPDATE `book` SET `id`=2,`price`='43' WHERE `id`=0

And this is what I expect it to be:

UPDATE `book` SET `id`=2,`price`='43' WHERE `id`=2

I know i can solve this by using the load() function. But I do not want the double query. I am not an expert in Data mapper pattern so correct me if I do not understand how this should work. How can I solve this?

Comment: ` price: <input  type="text" id="id" name="id" value="43" />` should be `  price: <input  type="text" id="id" name="price" value="43" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, the mapper should be *mapped* to a DB record.

In F3:

- you call `load()` to map a record
- you call `dry()` to check if a valid record has been mapped (dry=not mapped)

So in your case:

```
function update_book_price($f3){
  $mapper->load(array('id=?',$f3->get('POST.id')));
  if (!$mapper->dry()) {
    $mapper->copyfrom('POST');
    $mapper->update();
  }
}
```

A meaningful implementation of all of this would be to map a URL to a record:

```
$f3->map('/book/@id','Book');
```

Then in the `Book` class, you would check if `@id` is valid prior to executing any controller code:

```
class Book {

  protected $mapper;

  function get($f3) {
    //show book
  }

  function put($f3) {
    //update book
    $this->mapper->copyfrom('POST');
    $this->mapper->save();
  }

  function beforeRoute($f3,$params) {
    $this->mapper=new DB\SQL\Mapper(..);
    $this->mapper->load(array('id=?',$params['id']));
    if ($this->mapper->dry())
      $f3->error(404);//invalid id => book not found
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for details answer. So if I want to update a row with single query I must use "Regular" SQL?

Comment: What do you mean with "a single query"? In the example described above, `$this->mapper->save()` will execute a single `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: But before I can mapper->save() I must first mapper->load() and that 2 queries. But with regular SQL I can just: UPDATE books SET price=43 WHERE id=2 and that single quay. (Let say I do not need to check first if book exists)

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean. Then just skip my `beforeRoute` suggestion. It was just one example of implementation with the idea in mind to have an exact mapping between URL and DB record (like a RESTful interface, with correct HTTP statuses being returned).

Comment: But like I said without the mapper->load() the request that the mapper is creating is: UPDATE book SET id=2,price='43' WHERE id=0. Which cause an error. So would you use regular SQL instead?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was erroneous. Indeed, you can't avoid the 2 queries as the ORM needs that `SELECT` statement to properly map. So yes, if you can't afford that extra statement, go for raw SQL instead. It's all about balancing performance and coding comfort. Just remember that F3's ORM is [pretty fast](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r10&hw=peak&test=query&l=sg).

Comment: Thanks! that exactly the answer I needed